# I want to sum decimal values

Tags: c#

```
int sum=0;
for ( int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
   sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
}
total.Text = sum.ToString();Value) 
//showing error Input string was not in a correct format.
```

i have also tried with `sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());`
but still showing error.
and i even tried with double but still getting error

Please help

Comment: have you tried decimal.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any) ?

Comment: Can you create a string containing the value of dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), place a breakpoint and run it in the debugger. After that, update your question with what it returns.

Comment: Why do you need to convert to string and then parse back to integer? Try one of two solutions 1) sum += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value; 2) sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

Comment: `Input string was not in a correct format` This error is indicative that the string you are trying to parse isn't recognizable by the program as a numerical value. Make sure that it doesn't contain non-number characters such as letters or whitespace.

Comment: If you're trying to sum *decimal* values, why are you using *int*.Parse?

Comment: You need to provide some example data, for us. So it would easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

most likely the problem is that you are trying to parse a decimal number as in the title, but you are using a int.Parse function. int.Parse will fail if you give it a '5.25' value with the exact same error message you are getting: *"Input string was not in a correct format".*

You could try to parse your number with a decimal.Parse method

```
int sum=0;
for ( int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    //this decimal cast to integer will ignore any numbers after the decimal point. 
    //e.g.: 0.6 will add 0 (absolutely nothing) to the sum variable. 
    //I would recommend using the other solution below.
    sum += (int)decimal.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
}
total.Text = sum.ToString();
```

or change the integer sum to a decimal type all together

```
decimal sum = 0m;
for ( int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += decimal.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
}
total.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: i tryed with the code but showing Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, let me fix that

Comment: decimal sum=0;
           
                for ( int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    //sum += (int)decimal.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
                    sum +=Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                }
                total.Text = sum.ToString();

Comment: i also tried with this ...its taking number but if decimal value comes it will show error

Comment: try the bottom solution of my answer, Convert.ToInt32 is expecting an integer value, decimal.Parse should parse both integers and decimals

Comment: also, are there any empty cells that you are trying to parse?

Comment: no empty cells ,if i give TOint32 the function is woking fine with integer but decimal could it work ...

Comment: you cant convert to any int 8, 16, 32 or 64 a decimal number, if you don't want to use Parse, then use Convert.ToDecimal, but **not** ToIntXX